# Windows 8 apps interaction

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to create a Windows 8 store app that has got data as JSON and some REST APIs associated with it and will i be able to call that JSON data and APIs in another app that has been developed by me?Is it possible?I am using VS 2012 as IDE and my programming language is C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. On one hand, John is right, you can't interact between two Windows 8 apps directly. However, there are some techniques to sort of interact. Your first option is to interact via a service. Though this does not sound like what you could do, it is an option. Your second option is to save the data to a file (not in your local store, though) and let your second application option it using file activation. Your third option is to pass a JSON string to your second app using protocol activation. Both of those last two options, you should realize, are not real interaction. There is no guarantee that the second app (or the first) is even installed. And the interaction has to be started by the first app, and cannot be requested by the second. It's not much insofar as communication, but it gives you options depending on your scenario. I have a demo if you think it is interesting: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/walkthrough-using-windows-8-custom.html I hate to give work-a-rounds, but developers are innovative, and you would be using these techniques as they were designed. Not hacking them. But you might not get out of them what you want.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Windows 8 Store apps cannot communicate with each other in this way.  You could, however, easily develop a web service that both Store apps access and synchronize or communicate in that way.  That is, communicate through the cloud, not by having app-to-app communication on the client.